# Google API code

Tags: php, google-maps

I am working in PHP  need google map API code which take the location (Address) from user and show the pointer on map if this location is correct. Is any one know this code please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the two url's

1. https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3
2. [Google Maps + Geo-location w/ SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327161/google-maps-geo-location-w-sql)

you can search for "Code Sample PHP + Google Map" and you will find it.

THanks,
Jigar